# Connecting to Multiprocessing BaseManager works locally but not for remote server

Tags: python, server, proxy, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm currently using the [multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) functionality to serve some Python objects so that I could interact with their proxies on the client side.

After I start the server defined by the BaseManager, I try to connect at the client side to access the serveables. However, I'm seeing an `EoFError` only when the server and client exist on different hosts. If they were on the same local host, I can get access just fine.

server.py

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
password = "password".encode("utf-8")

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

a = {'one': 1}  # to be served
MyManager.register("get_a", callable=lambda: a)
m = MyManager(address=("127.0.0.1", 60000), authkey=password)
m.start()
# ... long running process ...
```

client.py

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
password = "password".encode("utf-8")

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register("get_a")
manager = MyManager(address=("SERVER_IP", 60000), authkey=password)
manager.connect()  # raises EoFError
```

Traceback:

```
File "client.py", line 20, in connect_to_executor_manager
               manager.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 512, in connect
              conn = Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 498, in Client
            answer_challenge(c, authkey)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 741, in answer_challenge
              message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
            buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
          buf = self._recv(4)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
          raise EOFError
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, but luckily, I created a clue when I modified my code in the course of debugging

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
password = "password".encode("utf-8")

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

a = {'one': 1}  # to be served
MyManager.register("get_a", callable=lambda: a)
m = MyManager(address=("127.0.0.1", 60000), authkey=password)
print(f"serving at address {m.address}")      # I added the equivalent of this line
m.start()
```

My test code caused the "serving at address..." line to print twice.  This made me think that the code was getting spawned twice.  I recall seeing somewhere that the server code should be contained in an `if __name__ == ...` block, so I tried that and things started working.
I'm no expert, but I think this error is caused during the spawn/forking/etc. process.  Long story short, you can modify your `server.py` code like so and it will likely work.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
password = "password".encode("utf-8")

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

a = {'one': 1}  # to be served
MyManager.register("get_a", callable=lambda: a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyManager(address=("127.0.0.1", 60000), authkey=password)
    m.start()
```

Comment: If your `server.py` only purpose is to start a server process, then instead of `m.start()` which starts a server in a different process (thus requiring pickling and protection of `if __name__...` block), you can simply do `s = m.get_server() ; s.serve_forever()`. This will start the server in the same process